# How To Highlight Section JDE Edward Background?

Tags: jdeveloper, jdedwards

I have a set of data which must draw user's attention. Therefore, i wish to highlight all of them with different background color. Can provide me the way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Set Grid Color - If you are designing form in FDA.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17984_01/doc.898/e14706/grid_controls.htm
Or, if you designing report with BI Publisher - 
try conditional rows - https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/entry/conditional_rows_and_columns
simplest way - put two identical rows one after another, format one with different color f.e. and conditionally show one or another.
plus you can control cell attributes (like background color).

Comment: hi, thank for ur suggestion. But is that any other way that i able to do it in RDA? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I did one report with the same request, to alert the user for some important information. And instead of use more colors, bold and big fonts, I used a label with a Wingding font with a alert sign in red color. Could be another approach for your report.

Comment: would u mind to provide the way how u did it last time?In RDA?

Comment: I just added a label and in its properties, changed the font to Wingding(or whatever font with symbols), formatted to bold and red. Then you should type the letter you want.

Comment: sorry for late reply. But i already try it. It still no able to highlight the whole section by using the method u provide to me. Isn't any other that i need to take before go through??thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly if your JDE runs under a unix operating system, you will not be able to access Wingding fonts unless you put them into the ressource directory.

x:\e812\system\resource\truetype

From then, the possibilies are endless with custom fonts. Here we bought a font creator software and we put logos and others images in it that we can use on the reports. We also designates the space letter to be a plain filled rectangle. We use labels filled with space using that font and we color them in red. You can put more labels over it and you get text over a red background and all this in the regular RDA interface.

Good luck

Comment: O ic. No wonder i no able to do it. By the way, may i know what font creator are u using? Because i now face logo creator problem. In order to do it, we must change the image to font type. Else can't recognize in RDA Jde.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get see your reply until now. We bought the FontCreator from High-Logic at high-logic.com.